# CodeIgniter : add 3 days to date fetched from database

Tags: php, codeigniter

My database table for date is lead_dateuploaded

```
$uploadDate = $date['lead_dateuploaded'];
// date format is (2016-10-20)
```

How can i add 3 days on that fetched data from database? im using CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think this will work.

```
$uploadDate = '2016-10-20';
$date = strtotime($uploadDate);
$date = strtotime("+3 day", $date);
$date = date('Y-m-d', $date);
echo $date;
```

Comment: it worked, but the problem is im getting 2016-Oct-15 1476504000. How can i get rid of the '1476504000'

Comment: $date = date('Y-m-d', $date);